# JExcelApi currency format on formula cell - file error

Tags: java, excel, formatting, spreadsheet, jexcelapi

I'm writing a spreadsheet with [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

I have two cells that I want to apply currency formatting to.  From reading the API I discovered jxl.write.NumberFormat, which seems to do what I want.  In my application I've written:

```
NumberFormat currency = new NumberFormat(NumberFormat.CURRENCY_DOLLAR);
WritableCellFormat currencyFormat = new WritableCellFormat(currency);

cells.add(new Formula(col, row, myFormula, currencyFormat));
```

col and row are the column and row to write to.
myFormula is the formula to be written.  There's one AVERAGE() and one SUM(), each of which is written to a different cell.
cells is an ArrayList which is writtten to the spreadsheet like this:

```
for (WritableCell cell : cells) {
    ws.addCell(cell);
}
```

(There's a try/catch block around that, but it's irrelavent at the moment.)

EDIT:  ws is a WritableSheet obtained with WritableWorkbook.getSheet(String name).  Everything else added to ws is written without a problem :)

The file writes successfully, but when I open it I get the message "File error.  Some number formats may have been lost."  The cells I formatted above have not been formatted in the Excel file.

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2003 SP3 and JExcelApi 2.6.10.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

you may find help here:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/jxl/demo/Write.java.html
- use

```
WritableCellFormat cfi3 = new WritableCellFormat
                (NumberFormats.ACCOUNTING_FLOAT);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NumberFormat currencyFormat = new NumberFormat(NumberFormat.CURRENCY_DOLLAR + " ###,###.00", NumberFormat.COMPLEX_FORMAT); 
WritableCellFormat lCurrencyFormat = new WritableCellFormat(currencyFormat);
Number currency = new Number(j, cnt, Double.parseDouble(lStr), lCurrencyFormat);
lSheet.addCell(currency);
```

This will definitely solve your purpose!

Comment: The `NumberFormat.COMPLEX_FORMAT` changed it all for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your currency format is not writen out.
You can try to create the formula cell first,then format it to currency format.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: No luck - "File error.  Some number formats may have been lost." when I open the spreadsheet.  The format is being written out but Excel can't read it properly.  Thanks anyway :)